# Efficient data serialization in haskell

Tags: haskell, serialization

I need to serialize a long list of relatively flat structures (it can be recursive, but most of time it isn't) - it's just a `Map` with sum types for number, text, bytestring, bool, utctime (and some sets and lists) as values. The key is that most of the time I will be just serializing the data and almost never read it so I need the serialization to be as fast as possible.

Originally I used `safecopy`, then I switched to `binary` (`Generic` instances), and in the end I tried `aeson` (0.10.0.0 HEAD - 0.10 has significantly faster encoding, the HEAD has a fixed instance for `UTCTime`). The `aeson` serialization outperforms both binary and `safecopy` (that's based on `cereal`) by a factor of 2, while providing shorter output.

I don't want to encode it to JSON, as by default my JSON encoding is lossy, so I would have to write a second encoder and parser to handle the sum types, but it's probably doable - maybe I could even use the generic instance from the `aeson` package. But I still wonder - is there any serialization method that would provide shorter output (the output is sent to DB, shorter output - better) while being faster than aeson? I didn't try `msgpack` yet, but it is based on `binary` so I don't have much faith in it.

Update: Provisionally, I ended up using `aeson`. Surprisingly it was faster than `BufferBuilder` (which was still faster than `binary`). I couldn't use the generic instance as I didn't want to define `ToJSON` for `ByteString` - so I ended writing the whole instance by hand. It seem to me that something like `msgpack` built on the same base as `aeson` would be a nice way to serialize data.

Comment: You might want to look through the full [Serialization category](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Serialization) on Hackage if you haven't yet. How confident are you that the problem is with serialization per se, and not with the way the serialized data are output? Can you show a code sample? Also, if you need to serialize a huge amount of data you almost never need to read, that suggests it might be worth the time to consider some sort of asymmetric compression algorithm that makes encoding very fast, if space matters to you.

Comment: I went through it and the only interesting is `beamable` (based on bytestring builder, so there is good chance it would work fast), that is unfortunately unmaintained and it doesn't compile on ghc 7.10. As for the performance - I am sure. I have written a test case that encodes the array and output ByteString length on the result.

Comment: What is your bottleneck? Writing to disk or the CPU time spent marshalling the data?

Comment: Why I asked:  If you have fast disks then you can Show the data in its full bloat and then compress later on. I seem to remember that Show performs well if output size is not a concern, but I can't find the reference.

Comment: The bottleneck is CPU when serializing the data. Show will be very slow as it outputs to String; aeson outputs to ByteString Builder which is very fast these days. I am sending the output to other process (postgresql) so smaller output would obviously improve performance (less data to manipulate - less CPU cycles burned), but the main concern is CPU cycles, compression wouldn't help here. I will write a serializer based on msgpack when I get some time off.